# My Mac's Google Drive no longer recognize my original Google Drive location and folder

Tags: google-drive

I just turned on my Mac Book pro and I started the Google Drive application , which prompted me to re-enter username and password, then it no longer recognizes the original Google Drive Folder that I have on my mac, namely "Google_Drive". And now it is trying to create a new "Google Drive" folder on my mac.

Question is how can i make it sync with my original "Google_Drive" folder instead of creating a brand new one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try taking a backup of the original Google drive folder into a temp folder, uninstall all Google drive software, delete both the folders, and then reinstall Google drive.

Finally move all the Google drive data from the temp folder to the new Google drive folder.